# How to deal with long, thin triangles when baking maps?

Tags: rendering, uv, texture-baking, baking

I’m currently encountering some visual artifacts when trying to bake an image from a specific UV map. See below an illustration of it:

[image]

This UV map has overall some nice properties in terms of angular/surface deformation. None of the triangles overlap each other as well. However, my issue comes from the zones circled in red: here are some long and thin triangles, less than a pixel’s length at their thinnest.

I use this UV map map to bake a Vector Displacement Map, ie a map storing the displacement needed to recreate an object from a plane. The map produced through this baking looks like so:

[image]

Sadly, the thin triangles of the UV map create some problems after baking the map and trying to recreate the object from it:

[image]

The areas circled in red show zones with visual artifacts, where some triangles essentially cross each other. Note that the circle at the bottom of this image corresponds to the same zone as the bottom circle of the UV map image.

My intuition is that because these triangles are so thin, when baking from this map, they essentially sometimes “fight” for the same pixel, leading to unpredictable results. A possible solution would thus be to bake the map by randomly sampling from it until the result stabilizes, the same way we do for a render. I’m however not sure if this is possible currently in Blender.

Note: In this project, modifying the UV map is sadly not really an option. It’s created automatically, and after some efforts the map that you see here is the best that I could get.

Comment: Everything should be shaded smooth when baking.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady not necessarily EVERYTHING, but there does need to be at least some smooth shading done to the vertex normals. It depends on the object. A hard surface object might have sharp edges, while an organic object would be 100% smooth shaded.

Comment: I don't understand why altering the UVs isn't an option. Aside from what has been mentioned re: Hard/Soft edges & vertex normals, that's what needs to be done to fix this issue. If you can't do that then you need to revise whatever algorithm it is that is automatically unwrapping the object. You're never going to get super clean bakes if you don't spend at least a little time unwrapping the object cleanly.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I just tried it but sadly it does not seem to change the quality much.

Comment: @Jakemoyo The challenge here is that the boundaries of the UV map need to be constant. Since the goal is to bake a vector displacement map, if the boundaries aren't fixed then the vertices are going to be pulled from a larger surface than covered by the object, resulting in ugly artifacts. The UV map here is essentially the best that the state of the art produces, hence why I'd like to think about solutions that do not focus on modifying it further. It also has nice properties in terms of area/angles preservations, so I think it's reasonable to find a way using it as is.